# How to identify a one vs. two-sided test (power analysis on proportions in R)

Tags: r, statistical-power, proportion, one-tailed-test, two-tailed-test

I have an oddly worded assignment for a power analysis on (paired) proportion data and I'm not sure if it matches the description of a one- or two-sided test. More specifically, I need to "see if I have sufficient (+80%) power to detect a 30% change (+ or -) in a mean proportion if that change actually occurred, and for which "groups" (column called "code")?".

Should I be doing one-sided tests where I A). compare the original proportion (p) with the hypothetical increase (p0) and set HA: p < p0 (`alternative = "less"`) and B). compare the original proportion (p) with the hypothetical decrease (p0) and set HA: p > p0 (`alternative = "greater"`)? Or, do two-sided tests (`alternative = "not equal"`) fit the problem better?

As I understand it, one-sided tests are "directional" and these seem to fit that description as they're about increases and decreases, but doesn't the two-sided test also tell me if a change could be detected at all, because it's about any difference?

Below is my R code and data for this problem. I have one column, "mean", is comprised of the most recent proportion data, a second column, "up", of hypothetical +30% increase values of the "mean", and a 3rd column, "down", of hypothetical -30% decrease values from the "mean".

```
library(pwrss)

# One-sided tests
decrease <- pwrss.z.prop(p = recent$mean, 
                         p0 = recent$down,
                         alpha = 0.05, 
                         power = NULL,
                         n = 47,
                         alternative = "greater", # or "not equal"?
                         arcsin.trans = TRUE)

increase <- pwrss.z.prop(p = recent$mean, 
                         p0 = recent$up,
                         alpha = 0.05, 
                         power = NULL,
                         n = 47,
                         alternative = "less", # or "not equal"?
                         arcsin.trans = TRUE)

recent$pwr_minus30 <- decrease$power
recent$pwr_plus30 <- increase$power

dput(recent)
structure(list(CYR = c(2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2022L, 2023L, 2023L, 
2023L, 2023L), Season = c("WET", "WET", "WET", "WET", "DRY", 
"DRY", "DRY", "DRY"), plot = c("Far", "Goldspotted Killifish", 
"Gulf Pipefish", "Pal", "Far", "Goldspotted Killifish", "Gulf Pipefish", 
"Pal"), n = c(47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L), mean = c(0.36, 
0.77, 0.3, 0.47, 0.6, 0.45, 0.7, 0.47), key = c("2022_WET", "2022_WET", 
"2022_WET", "2022_WET", "2023_DRY", "2023_DRY", "2023_DRY", "2023_DRY"
), up = c(0.468, 1.001, 0.39, 0.611, 0.78, 0.585, 0.91, 0.611
), down = c(0.252, 0.539, 0.21, 0.329, 0.42, 0.315, 0.49, 0.329
), code = c("2022_WET_Far", "2022_WET_Goldspotted Killifish", 
"2022_WET_Gulf Pipefish", "2022_WET_Pal", "2023_DRY_Far", "2023_DRY_Goldspotted Killifish", 
"2023_DRY_Gulf Pipefish", "2023_DRY_Pal"), pwr_minus30 = c(0.487053173852327, 
0.958236773382266, 0.411269410945641, 0.631748489380889, 0.798767323687277, 
0.605183829003879, 0.90549037666744, 0.631748489380889), pwr_plus30 = c(0.000812487798858119, 
NaN, 0.00161275163555041, 0.000164590549969312, 7.14631094034246e-06, 
0.000230270040271874, 3.06892320445229e-08, 0.000164590549969312
)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(CYR = 2022:2023, 
    Season = c("WET", "DRY"), .rows = structure(list(1:4, 5:8), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Comment: I would immediately think of a two-sided test when I read "to detect a 30% change (+ or -) in a mean proportion". But it can be a question how "(+ or -)" should be interpreted - can you double check with the source of origin of that question?

Comment: @Ute Yes, so "(+ or -)" should actually mean both an increase and decrease. I now also take this to mean two separate two-sided tests. One test was p=mean occurrence vs p0=(mean + (mean*0.3)) (30% increase, as long as it's not above 1.0) and another was p=mean vs p0=mean*70% (30% decrease). Does that seem right?

Comment: You should in practice never do two separate tests for the hypotheses "+ 30%" and "- 30%" concurrently, because you would have twice the risk of rejecting the null hypothesis with one of these tests. Instead, one would do a two sided test. Such a test has lower power versus given alternatives. So if your alternative includes both possibilities, do a two sided test. If the question was to derive power of one sided tests separately, it is a different thing. I do not understand which interpretation of the question is the correct one, unfortunately (not a native speaker ;-))

Comment: @Ute Aha! I didn't know about the risks of doing multiple tests, good to know! I am a native speaker and I'm having trouble with the interpretation as well, so don't worry about that, haha. Thank you for the information! I think my alternative includes both possibilities, but how would one do a test with an alternative hypothesis with 2 possibilities? Sorry if I'm misinterpreting your answer!

Comment: Search for two sided test: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=two+sided+test. Essentially, you do both tests but with a critical threshold that corresponds to half the significance level, i.e., as if you testet at $\alpha=2.5\%$ instead of $\alpha = 5\%$

Comment: @Ute, Oh ok, and the tests would still be p=mean vs. p0=mean*0.7 (30% decrease of the mean) and the 2nd test is p=mean vs. p0=(mean + mean*0.3) a 30% increase of the mean? For example, if the mean=0.5: p=0.5 vs. p0=0.35, and p=0.5 vs p0=0.65?

Comment: No, if the mean=0.5: still p=0.5 vs. p0=0.2, and p=0.5 vs p0=0.8. You only change alpha to 0.025.